# Android: Same models, One of mobile is getting updated apps from Play store but another mobile isn't getting update apps

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am having the two mobile with same model(Note 4), But one of mobile is getting updated apps from playstore and another mobile cann't getting..

Example:
X- mobile and Y-mobile(same model and versions)
X-mobile is getting update apps from play store
Y-Mobile is not getting update apps(X and Y mobile having same apps)
Need some help on this ?

Comment: How long have you been waiting? Google does not distribute the build on all devices at once, updates may be received after a while

Comment: Are you sure the app on your other phone (Which does not show an update option) is a release version / was installed from app store?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe those apps are using play store's staged rollout feature.